# If statement seemingly being evaluated incorrectly as false? Java

Tags: java, javafx

Hi I am building a simple calculator program, wherein there is a double num1, double num2, string myOperator. For instance the values may hold the following respectively: 1, 2, "+". This would later equate to the equation 1 + 2 = 3;. For my gui I have number buttons, and operation buttons (+,-,/,*) that set the variables value.

```
public double num1, num2, num3;
public String myOperator;
```

Here is my method:

```
    @FXML
    private void handleSolution(ActionEvent event){
        if(myOperator == "+"){
            System.out.println("plus");
        }else if(myOperator == "-") {
            System.out.println("minus");
        }else if(myOperator == "*"){
            System.out.println("multiplication");
        }else if(myOperator == "/"){
            System.out.println("division");
        }else{
            System.out.println("wtf");
            System.out.println(myOperator);
            System.out.println(myOperator.length());
        }
    }
```

Regardless of which button I click (+,-,/,*) in the gui, 'wtf' is always printed, so I added myOperator to see what is actually printed out and myOperator.length to see if I perhaps had the correct character, but added a space incorrectly.

Here were my results:

If I press the [+] button the system prints out:

```
+
1
```

If I press the [-] button the system prints out:

```
-
1
```

If I press the [/] button the system prints out

```
/
1
```

If I press the [*] button the system prints out:

```
*
1
```

Can anyone tell me how to fix this or what I am doing incorrectly?

Comment: Dont use `==` to check for equality but equals.

Comment: Objects and primitives work quite differently in Java. If you declared the operator variable as a `char` primitive ( `public char myOperator`) and put the operators inside single quotes in the if statements, this would work. But because `String`s are objects, you need to use `equals()` to compare the _content_ of the string.